# What is the best way to distribute Python apps and interpreters in an offline environment?

Tags: python, windows, software-distribution

What is the best way to distribute Python apps and interpreters in an offline environment?

The requirements I have to satisfy are:

1. The OS of the device to be distributed is win7 or win10.
2. There are an offline environment where most networks are not connected.
3. The Python applications I want to deploy use several other Python packages, such as pyqt, numpy, and so on. These packages must also be distributed together.
   In the development environment, we installed the package with pip.
4. It may or may not already have a different version of Python installed in the environment being deployed. My app may not work with an already installed version of Python.
5. The Python interpreter should also be included in the distribution, as that user's PC may not have Python.

Is it possible to distribute one installation?

Or is there a good distribution method in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Buildout](https://pypi.org/project/zc.buildout/) might be what you're looking for.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536097/6685140)